# Sim7600G giving Error to every AT command when using with ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32, uart, gsm

I am having some issues with my GSM module. I am trying to test it with arduino ide serial monitor but sim7600G response ERROR to every at command. when i directly use micro usb port on sim7600 i was able to log data to aws using tera term software but esp32 get Error response everytime.

Here is the code I am using:

```
//#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

//SoftwareSerial SIM900A(27,32);
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

HardwareSerial MySerial(1);
String msg;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  MySerial.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, 16, 17);  // Setting the baud rate of GSM Module
  Serial.begin(115200);  // Setting the baud rate of Serial Monitor (Arduino)
  delay(100);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {}
  msg = Serial.readString();
  MySerial.println(msg);

  while (MySerial.available() == 0) {}
  msg = MySerial.readString();

  //msg.replace("\n", "");
  Serial.println(msg);
  msg = "";
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following output:

```
RDY

+CPIN: READY

SMS DONE

PB DONE

AT

ERROR

AT

ERROR

AT

ERROR

AT
```

What can I do to fix this, and what does this output mean in general?

Comment: Just a suggestion - might be that the GSM module is expecting a line to be terminated with `\r\n` and your terminal application only sends `\n`